# Azure Bot Framework - Unreachable QnA Maker Service

Tags: c#, botframework

We are having trouble calling a QnA Maker knowledge base from the Bot Framework. The code compiles fine. The bot emulator also opens and runs. The code is based on the following GitHub repo:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch

In the repo's code, there is a dispatch model with two LUIS instances and a QnA Maker instance. We were able to successfully change the dispatch code to instead point to our three QnA Maker instances. This worked in the bot emulator, and we were able to communicate with no errors or exceptions happening.

HOWEVER - we are using QnA Maker KB's with follow-up prompts. Although the code was running, none of the follow up prompts were being generated; only the answers were being returned. I found the following blog post, and attempted to modify ONE of our functions to be able to grab the follow-up prompts from the QnA Maker KB:

https://joji.me/en-us/blog/implement-follow-up-prompt-for-qna-bot/

This did not completely break our code. The code still compiles and runs. We can successfully ask questions that direct to the other QnA Maker KB's (which returns answers, but no follow up prompts) but we return the following errors when we give an input that directs the dispatch tool to our modified code (where we attempt to return follow-up prompts):

Console Error Messages: (note: this error only happens when we are testing the bot in the Bot Emulator and give input that directs the Dispatch to this KB)

```
fail: Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter[0]
      [OnTurnError] unhandled error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.DispatchBot.ProcessfindPartQnAAsync(ITurnContext`1 turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\c50941\source\repos\AIM bot\BotBuilder-Samples\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\14.nlp-with-dispatch\Bots\DispatchBot.cs:line 155
   at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.DispatchBot.DispatchToTopIntentAsync(ITurnContext`1 turnContext, String intent, RecognizerResult recognizerResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\c50941\source\repos\AIM bot\BotBuilder-Samples\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\14.nlp-with-dispatch\Bots\DispatchBot.cs:line 109
   at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.DispatchBot.OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext`1 turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\c50941\source\repos\AIM bot\BotBuilder-Samples\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\14.nlp-with-dispatch\Bots\DispatchBot.cs:line 88
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ActivityHandler.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.TenantIdWorkaroundForTeamsMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

QnAMaker Trace: (from the Bot Emulator)

```
Unable to find a QnA Maker service with Knowledge Base ID d1f*****-****-****-****-************. Please add a QnA Maker service to your bot.
```

Based on research of other's problems, we know that it is common to not have the right information in the appsettings.json. We have triple checked that this is correct on our end. That is also evidenced that we can call our other two Qna Maker KB's successfully, as their credentials are stored by the same method and in the same file. Here is our modified function to call the specific KB, with the intent of also getting the follow-up prompts. Based on the console errors, this is where it seems our error would be. Also, this is the only function we have modified since the entire program was working fully: (We have commented ERROR at the lines where the output logs have told us there is an issue)

```
private async Task ProcessfindPartQnAAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("ProcessfindPartQnAAsync");

    var results = await _botServices.findPartQnA.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext);

    // The actual call to the QnA Maker service.
    var response = await _botServices.findPartQnA.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext);
    if (response != null && response.Length > 0)
    {
        // create http client to perform qna query
        var followUpCheckHttpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

        // add QnAAuthKey to Authorization header
        followUpCheckHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", _configuration["findPartQnAEndpointKey"]);



        // construct the qna query url
        var url = $"{_configuration["findPartQnAEndpointHostName"]}/knowledgebases/{_configuration["findPartQnAKnowledgebaseId"]}/generateAnswer";
                
        // post query
        // ***** ERROR *****
        var checkFollowUpJsonResponse = await followUpCheckHttpClient.PostAsync(url, new StringContent("{​​​​\"question\":\"" + turnContext.Activity.Text + "\"}​​​​", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // parse result
        var followUpCheckResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FollowUpCheckResult>(checkFollowUpJsonResponse);

        // initialize reply message containing the default answer
        var reply = MessageFactory.Text(response[0].Answer);

        // ***** ERROR *****
        if (followUpCheckResult.Answers.Length > 0 && followUpCheckResult.Answers[0].Context.Prompts.Length > 0)
        {
            // if follow-up check contains valid answer and at least one prompt, add prompt text to SuggestedActions using CardAction one by one
            reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions();
            reply.SuggestedActions.Actions = new List<CardAction>();
            for (int i = 0; i < followUpCheckResult.Answers[0].Context.Prompts.Length; i++)
            {
                var promptText = followUpCheckResult.Answers[0].Context.Prompts[i].DisplayText;
                reply.SuggestedActions.Actions.Add(new CardAction() { Title = promptText, Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = promptText });
            }
        }
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
    }
    else
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("No QnA Maker answers were found."), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

We believe that there must be something wrong with the way that we are constructing the URL... though we have triple-checked that all of the info is correct as it is named in our appsettings.json and that we have the right credentials from our Azure services stored there. Thank you for any help that can be provided.

Comment: Have you tried to test the setup in any other channel other than the Emulator? Also, for all the 3 QNAMaker instances, none of the follow-up prompts is generated?

Comment: No, none of the follow-up prompts are generated for any of the QnA maker instances. The ProcessfindPartQnAAsync I pasted is our first attempt to generate the follow-up prompts for a QnA instance. We used https://joji.me/en-us/blog/implement-follow-up-prompt-for-qna-bot/ as a reference. I had done this on my own before and gotten it to work.

Comment: We have not used a channel to test other than the Emulator.

Comment: @ranusharao thank you for any help or advice you can provide!

Comment: What is your question? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: What can we change in our current code to make the errors disappear and our bot work? @KyleDelaney

Comment: @coleconklin1 - Have you tried this sample that includes follow-up prompts using a QnA Maker dialog? https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/49.qnamaker-all-features

Comment: We have tried that sample. It unfortunately does not include the use of a Dispatch LUIS instance to direct user input towards multiple QnA Maker models - a requirement of this Bot. A good place to start may be: Why, after deserializing the JSON object, does the FollowUpCheckResult variable give us an error? that is the line where we get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

Comment: @KyleDelaney ^^^

Comment: @coleconklin1 - I could help you try to diagnose that problem by getting you to trace the HTTP request being made so you can see if it looks correct and so you could replicate the request in Postman, but I think it's likely that you shouldn't be making the request to begin with. It looks to me like you're trying to make the same request twice, first by calling `GetAnswersAsync` and second by calling `PostAsync` directly. Can you explain why you're doing this, and are you aware that you can get the follow-up prompt data from the results of the `GetAnswersAsync` call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223180/discussion-between-kyle-delaney-and-coleconklin1).

Comment: @KyleDelaney thank you for your help. It turns out, that this error was stemming from a corrupted QnA Maker instance. Once we recreated the QnA Maker service and updated the credentials to the new instance, our code worked. HOWEVER, your point about getting the follow-up prompt dat from the GetAnswersAsync call is interesting and I will investigate this further - because it may be more efficient that our current method. Thank you for all of your teams help!!!

Comment: Please go ahead and accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure your QnA Maker instance is not corrupt by creating a new QnA Maker service
2. Make sure you don't call the same QnA Maker service with the same utterance multiple times per turn